# Замена в тегах XML, слово или пару слов через XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl

Здравствуйте помогите в xml сделать замену в атрибуте **gotovnost**. Нужно искать не всю строчку в атрибуте, а только слово или несколько слов и заменять на нужное. **Например:** `gotovnost="8 декабря 2022, c 10 до 18 часов"`. Нужно в атрибуте **gotovnost** вместо слово **декабрь** поставить **цифру месяца (12)**, вместо **часов** написать **time**, ну и тд. а все остальное осталось. Как это дописать в код **XSLT 3**

**XML**

```
    <zakazy>
    <params KodProverki=""
            obrabotki1="Жесткий картон, 350 гр."
            obrabotki1="KREATO_350_B3"
            gotovnost="8 декабря 2022, c 10 до 18 часов"
    />  
</zakazy>
```

**XSL 3.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" expand-text="yes" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:variable name="find_and_replace" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'Жесткий картон, 350 гр.'" select="'Картон 350 гр.'"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'KREATO_350_B3'" select="'Креато 350 гр.'"/>
            <!--Добавьте столько пар ключ/значение, сколько необходимо-->
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@*[.=map:keys($find_and_replace)]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" select="map:get($find_and_replace, .)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Желаемый результат XSLT 3.0**

```
<?xml version='1.0' 
encoding='utf-8' ?>
<zakazy>
  <params KodProverki=""
    obrabotki1Name="Картон 350 гр."
    obrabotki1="Креато 350 гр."
    gotovnost="8.12.2022, c 10 до 18 time"
/>
</zakazy>
```

Comment: Задавая вопрос XSLT, вам необходимо предоставить [минимальный воспроизводимый пример] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Входной XML.
(2) Ваша логика и XSLT, который пытается ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат, основанный на образце XML в #1 выше.
(4) Процессор XSLT и его соответствие стандартам XSLT: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 или 4.0.
Все в вопросе в виде текста, без картинок.

Comment: №3 отсутствует.

Comment: @ Yitzhak Khabinsky. Вроде все исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующий XSLT.

Оно использует очень полезный для такого сценария `xsd:analyze-string` оператор.

Разобьем все предложение на 3 группы:

1. `regex-group(1)` - для цифр.
2. `regex-group(2)` - для слов, окруженных пробелами.
3. `xsl:non-matching-substring` для всего остального.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                expand-text="yes" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"
                omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:variable name="find_and_replace" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'Жесткий картон, 350 гр.'"
                           select="'Картон 350 гр.'"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'KREATO_350_B3'" select="'Креато 350 гр.'"/>
            <!--Добавьте столько пар ключ/значение, сколько необходимо-->
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@*[.=map:keys($find_and_replace)]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"
                       select="map:get($find_and_replace, .)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*[ends-with(., 'часов')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\d{{1,2}})|(\s\w*\s)">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="regex-group(1)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="regex-group(2)">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <!--добавить все месяцы, следуя тому же шаблону-->
                                <xsl:when test=". = ' ноября '">
                                    <xsl:text>.11.</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=". = ' декабря '">
                                    <xsl:text>.12.</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'часов','time')"/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает. А можно чтобы поиск был не в конкретной переменной а во всех переменных, чтобы изменить все совпадения? Еще раз спасибо и **ВЫ ЛУЧШИЙ!!!**

Comment: Вроде нашел чтобы изменял во всех переменных. Заменил в `<xsl:template match="@gotovnost">
  <xsl:attribute name="gotovnost">` на `<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">`

Comment: при тесте кода понял, что мне нужна только дата, все остальное не нужно, подскажите где и что подправить. **Должно получиться так** `<?xml version='1.0' 
encoding='utf-8' ?>
<zakazy>
  <params KodProverki=""
    obrabotki1Name="Картон 350 гр."
    obrabotki1="Креато 350 гр."
    gotovnost="8.12.2022"
/>
</zakazy>` **И еще раз огромное спасибо за помощь, вы очень крутой!!**

Comment: Я скорректировал ответ чуть точнее. Так будет меньше нагрузки. Проверьте это.

Comment: не вижу скорректированного ответа? Где смотреть?

Comment: `<xsl:template match="@*[ends-with(., 'часов')]">`

Comment: Пожалуйста, попробуйте сделать это самостоятельно: `gotovnost="8.12.2022"`

Comment: Спасибо увидел. **А как сделать чтобы была одна дата, часы не нужны?** Извините за беспокойство.  **Должно получиться так** `<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='utf-8' ?> <zakazy>   <params KodProverki=""     obrabotki1Name="Картон 350 гр."     obrabotki1="Креато 350 гр."     gotovnost="8.12.2022" /> </zakazy>`

Comment: Пожалуйста, попробуйте сделать это самостоятельно: gotovnost="8.12.2022"

Comment: Пробовал самостоятельно у меня не получилось. Удалял `<xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'часов','time')"/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>` текст получалось `gotovnost="7.12.2022 c 10 до 18"/>`  с  **10 до 18** не могу убрать ((

Comment: Пожалуйста, задайте новый вопрос. ##1-4

Comment: Вам просто нужно опубликовать новый вопрос. У меня уже есть на него ответ.